# Ping url and get status in java

Tags: java

```
         URLPing urlPing = new URLPing();
         PingResponse pingResponse = urlPing.ping(URLName);
         if(pingResponse.getResponseCode() == 200){
                response = true;
         }
         else{
                response=false;
         }
```

This is what i have tried at present.

Comment: First, post the code please. Second, you might not need ping/wget if you use URLConnection to connect to URLs.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584210/preferred-java-way-to-ping-a-http-url-for-availability

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584210/preferred-java-way-to-ping-a-http-url-for-availability

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799938/httpurlconnection-timeout-question

Answer (score 4):

[Ping URL from JAVA Code](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-ping-url-from-android.html)

```
public static boolean pingUrl(final String address) {
 try {
  final URL url = new URL("http://" + address);
  final HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  urlConn.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 10); // mTimeout is in seconds
  final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  urlConn.connect();
  final long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  if (urlConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
   System.out.println("Time (ms) : " + (endTime - startTime));
   System.out.println("Ping to "+address +" was success");
   return true;
  }
 } catch (final MalformedURLException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
 } catch (final IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To ping a URL:

```
public static boolean exists()
{
   try
   {
      return (Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 google.com").waitFor() == 0);
   }
   catch (IOException | InterruptedException exception)
   {
      exception.printStackTrace();
      // Handler
   }

   return false;
}
```