# How to manage connection lost with HttpURLConnection?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I have a `Service` that manages downloading tasks using using `HttpURLConnection`.

I use a custom `isNetworkAvailable` method before performing any HTTP request, but I'm wondering how to manage connection lost during the request.

Shall I call my `isNetworkAvailable` method in the `while` loop (which means lots of calls)? What's the standard way to manage connection lost with `HttpURLConnection`?

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, MODE_PRIVATE | MODE_APPEND);               

BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

byte[] data = new byte[1024];
int x = 0;

while ((x = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
    outputStream.write(data, 0, x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest catching `IOException` and if it happens, giving the user an option to retry or cancel.  You may want to use `setConnectTimeou`t (see [HttpURLConnection timeout question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799938/httpurlconnection-timeout-question) for an example of how to use it) to make sure you get an error in a reasonable time.

As a random comment -- if you're reading data into a reasonably large buffer, as you are here, there's little or no point using a `BufferedInputStream`; just use the input stream returned by `connection.getInputStream()` directly.  The only reason to use a `BufferedInputStream` is if you're reading in small chunks, e.g. one byte at a time.

Comment: Ok, I've just seen that `IOException` has a `ConnectException` subclass. I'll use that, thanks. About the `BufferedInputStream`: I need small chunks to display the download progress.