# ETIMEOUT (Connection timed out) when using the phone

Tags: android-studio, localhost, database-connection, connection-string, connection-timeout

So as you can see I can access my webservice without any problems using the browser:
[image]

BUT when I try to connect to my webservice using the phone I get this error:

```
=error in background: failed to connect to /192.168.30.1 (port 28389): connect failed: ETIMEOUT (Connection timed out)
```

Here are the classes and methods I am using: https://pastebin.com/pv0s5B5r

I posted the code per pastebin as maybe it will look large.. I get the error in the controller.

Any ideas? As you can see I have full access using the browser...

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799938/httpurlconnection-timeout-settings

Comment: @RajasekaranM I still get the error... => connection failed and after that the illegalargument exception. Is my URL maybe wrong?

Comment: is running on postman?

Comment: @RajasekaranM yes it runs on postman. I am able to run in on each server but idk why I cant run it on the phone.

Comment: add read and write time to httpclient